# Using both tkinter and Python shell windows in a program

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Is it considered bad practise/style to run `tkinter` based Python programs as `.py`, instead of `.pyw`, such that both the graphics window and the Python shell window are used? Or it is simply a matter of what works best in a particular situation?

I have tried to search for this, but no luck.

Comment: If you don't want a console window to be shown and there is no code in the script requires the console, then use .pyw.

Comment: .pyw is used to suppress the shell window, so you don't have to see multiple windows opening.

Comment: On Windows, `.pyw` scripts have no `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` input and output files or a console window create in which to display output and or accept input typed by the user — typically programs with a GUI (like the kind `tkinter` supports). It not a requirement, but if you don't an empty console window will appear (usually briefly) whenever you run your script.

Comment: So, from what you are saying I gather that it is not considered a bad interface to have a console and a GUI at the same time.